# How to get the last element of an array field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I've this document indexed (index: customer-v1, type: customer, _id: 123):

`GET customers-v1/customer/123`

which result in:

```
{
  "_index" : "customers-v1",
  "_type" : "customer",
  "_id" : "123",
  ...
  "_source" : {
    "name": ...
    "age": ...
    "payments": [
      {"month": "2021-01", "amount": 10},
      {"month": "2021-02", "amount": 100},
      {"month": "2021-03", "amount": 30},
      {"month": "2021-04", "amount": 56},
    ]
  } 
}
```

Now I need to return a computed field(along with original data), via script, it must return the last item on field `payments`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scripted_fields` in search query to find the last element of an array.

```json
POST customers-v1/_search
{
    "stored_fields": [
        "_source"
    ],
    "script_fields": {
        "lastPayment": {
            "script": {
                "source": "def payments = params['_source']['payments']; return payments[payments.length - 1];",
                "lang": "painless"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above query will fetch the source along with the last element of the array:

```json
{
    "took": 4,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "customers-v1",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "...",
                    "age": "...",
                    "payments": [
                        {
                            "month": "2021-01",
                            "amount": 10
                        },
                        {
                            "month": "2021-02",
                            "amount": 100
                        },
                        {
                            "month": "2021-03",
                            "amount": 30
                        },
                        {
                            "month": "2021-04",
                            "amount": 56
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "fields": {
                    "lastPayment": [
                        {
                            "amount": 56,
                            "month": "2021-04"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: how to use explicity for GET API?

Comment: this method you provided me is only return message field, and i need the whole `_source` plus `computed_field`

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: thks, it anwser one of my questions, return _source plus computed field, but still a question, how to do it directly to the `GET` endpoint, `index/type/<id>`? it is possible?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible since GET API does not allow us to provide payload. However, you can use search API to fetch documents based on their IDs. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html